# Matplotlib scatter plot, data from CSV are plotting vertically instead of scattering

Tags: matplotlib

I have obtained a CSV file where I am trying to plot the date on the x-axis and the measurement on the y-axis. I was initially having overlapping issues when I plotted the x-axis, but converted the dates column to datetime. Prior to converting, my graph looked like this:

[image]

After converting and fixing up my overlapped x-tick labels, my graph now looks like this:

[image]

I want to maintain the scatter of the first plot and the x-tick label format of the second plot. My code is as follows (minus title, x and y labels, figsize, etc.)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

data = pd.read_csv("epa.csv")

data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"].astype(str)) # script from first graph includes everything but these two lines
data["Date"] = data["Date"].dt.strftime("%b %y")

plt.scatter(data.Date, data.PM, color="#f049d0", s=1)

plt.show()
```

I wasn't sure how to formulate my question well enough to find what I was looking for online. Have a clue what I should look into?

Comment: It would really help to have the data. Can you post your data to an external link?

Comment: You need to plot the data as is and then change the xticklabels. `data["Date"].dt.strftime("%b %y")` changes the underlying data, which is not what you want.